# Tomcat shows NoClassDefFoundError for class in my project

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, vaadin

I've got a Vaadin project that uses JIRA's SOAP API. It runs fine in Eclipse, but attempting to make it work in IntelliJ and with Maven is slowly driving me mad, though I feel I'm close to completion.

Whenever I deploy my application to a local Tomcat server, all I get is a stack trace caused by this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError   
be.azvub.jira.service.JiraSoapServiceServiceLocator.getJirasoapserviceV2(JiraSoapServiceServiceLocator.java:53)
```

This class exists, because nothing has changed since I moved them from eclipse and because I can open the .java file and see that there are no errors in there. I can remove the luine of code that makes the call to this class and all is well, so it's a localised problem. The problem class is in a different package from my Application class (which still works), where the call to it is made.

What's causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you use maven with Eclipse and IntelliJ (or) only with IntelliJ?

Comment: So, can you tell me how did you specify the dependency for that JIRA's SOAP API?

Comment: It uses Axis.jar (code generated from a wsdl), the jar is in a folder in my project since it was like that in Eclipse, and dependency is detailed like so: 
'<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
   <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>'

Comment: be.azvub.jira.service.JiraSoapServiceServiceLocator is this class in any jar try to add that jar dependency and also set <scope>runtime</scope>. If that jar has no pom then try to install that jar to local repository using install command in maven. then add that installed jar as dependency.

Comment: It's not in a jar, it's just a java file in a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it now after debugging ...

IntelliJ usually auto-creates a folder /lib under your /src folder inside your project, and then it would tell your project that all LIBs are in there, on that basis; we usually assume that it's the place to put all your LIBs in there as well.

Although with that setup your project would compile fine since IntelliJ can link up to your JARs However, with that sort of setup Tomcat will fail to execute, since Tomcat expects to find the classes under /WEB-INF/lib,...

Therefore, the solution is to:

> 1) Drag your LIB folder (sorry I mean "/lib") from /src/lib to be
>   under /web/WEB-INF directory
>
> 2) You would get a warning about moving classes / JARs, say YES.
>
> (You need to tell your project to re-map your existing pre-defined
>   LIBs to the new folder):
>
> 3) From the main menu, select FILE -> Project Structure
>
> 4) Select
>   Libraries from the left menu
>
> 5) If you don't see any existing libs, then you're done, click OK
>
> 6) If you do see libs in there, then:
>
> 7) Click on each LIB from the
>   middle-list, and then remove the ones that can't be located,
>
> 8) Re-add them again from the new location
>
> 9) Repeat (7) to all other LIBs.
>
> 10) OK,

RE-compile, your project should deploy on Tomcat now and work fine.

Regards
Heider

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how I did it, but by fixing an unrelated problem, this got fixed along with it.

I changed the Web Resource Directory under File | Project Structure | Facets (So the app could find Vaadin's theme folder under the WebContent directory instead of the default src/main/webapp it was set to) Neither of the folders actually contain the class that was giving me problems.

I also forced Maven to reimport everything, as I have done several times before, but now I used the option to do so under the project's context menu in the Project Explorer instead of the Maven Projects tab, so maybe that made a difference? Maven is still largely voodoo to me, but at least everything seems to be working normally now.

But thank you for your assistance anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the build path, check to see if the class you are calling is present in the build path of the project.